# How to prevent props from reseting when child component updates?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

`avatarid` and `relationlist` are passed from parent, when an image is uploaded, avatarid changed, but avatarid will be reseted to original if relationlist is changed (add or remove item from RelationTable component).

I think it is that the`RelationTable` rerendering causes the parent to reload. How can I stop such reseting when child component updates. Thanks.

```
<template>

    <el-upload
      class="avatar-uploader"
      action
      :http-request="uploadAvatar"
      accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png"
      :after-upload="uploadAvatarSucc"
    >
    <RelationTable ref="relationTable" :relationlist="relationlist" @delete="removeRelation" />

</template>

export default {
  name: 'relation-component',
  props: {
    avatarid: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    relationlist: {
      type: Array,
      default: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadAvatarSucc(res) {
      this.avatarid = res.imageId
    },
    removeRelation(index) {
      if (this.relationlist.length > 0) {
        this.relationlist.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant stop it - in Vue props are [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) only. If you open the browser Dev Tools you should see error message from Vue telling you exactly this.

Changing `relationlist` sort of works because you are updating the array in-place (modifying existing instance instead of replacing it ....which is not possible with numbers etc.) but if you try something else (for example creating new array with filter), it will stop working too.

Only *correct* way around it is to emit event and let the parent component (owner of the data) to do the modifications (google "props down events up"). This of course becomes harder and harder as the depth of the component tree and the distance between data owner and child component increases. And that's one of the reasons why global state management tools like Vuex exist....

Another way is to pass the data by single prop of type Object. As long as you only modify object's properties (not replacing the object itself), it will work. But this **not recommended and considered anti-pattern...**

Comment: OK, if I understand it right, the best way is to use global state management, but since it's the second level of the component tree, I will first try to emit event to change parent value. Actually there are two more Object type props in the code, I had wondered why they didn't reset, and I got answer from your last paragraph. Thanks.